# Safe countdown loop

Tags: c, for-loop, reverse, unsigned-integer

The following code will produce a segfault due to integer overflow when i reaches -1. If I change "unsigned int i" to "char i", then it will work fine but will generate a compiler warning "array subscript has type 'char'". Declaring it as "int i" will work fine and there won't be compiler warning but it feels like there should be. After all int is signed as well and could go also negative.
My question is, is there a safe, elegant, idiomatic way to write such loops in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int i;
    char a[10] = {0};

    for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("a[%d]: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be signed, otherwise it's a forever loop (unsigned are always `>=0` and wraparaound overflow/underflow is fine on them). Going from  `0` to `-1` isn't underflow/overflow, going left of `INT_MIN` or right of `INT_MAX` is.

Comment: To discuss C clearly, you should learn and use proper terminology. `i` cannot overflow or reach −1. Unsigned arithmetic is defined to wrap, so, when `i` is zero, `i--` wraps it around to the maximum representable value, `UINT_MAX`. This is different from *overflow* in the meaning of the C standard. So you should say that `i` wraps (not overflows) and becomes large (not −1), and then there is a segment fault because `a[i]` attempts to access an element out of bounds (not directly because `i` overflowed or wrapped).

Comment: Check your compiler options. Your compiler should issue a warning when `i` is an `unsigned int` because in this case, the condition `i >= 0` is always true and the loops never ends.

Comment: Re “My question is, is there a safe, elegant, idiomatic way to write such loops in C?”: I am commenting rather than answering because I would want to consider or research further, but I would not say there is a single idiomatic solution. This situation is a nuisance, and it is often written around in various ways. We might discuss using `i != -1`, as it works with both signed types and unsigned types at least as wide as `int` (because the −1 will be converted to the maximum value). That could be reasonable as an idiomatic solution except it fails for narrower unsigned types.

Comment: I can't think of a good reason why a compiler would warn about using `char` as an array subscript. Maybe if you use `int8_t` it will be silent, since that type doesn't suggest that it's intended to hold characters.

Comment: @DanGetz: The condition `i >= 0` means that with a signed int, the code isn't run with `i = -1`. OP is aware of that. The question is not what is wrong with this code or why this happens. The question is “is there a safe, elegant, idiomatic way to write such loops in C?”

Comment: @xhienne: Re “Check your compiler options”: OP is not complaining of failing code or asking for a diagnosis for it. The question is “is there a safe, elegant, idiomatic way to write such loops in C?”

Comment: @DanGetz: The post explicitly states “My question is, is there a safe, elegant, idiomatic way to write such loops in C?” Everything else is preamble.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The OP said the compiler issued a warning when they changed from `unsigned int` to `char`.

Comment: @Barmar: I see. A good reason to warn about that is `char` may or may not be signed, so using it as an array subscript is hazardous for code intended to be portable. You could write and test code on your implementation with unsigned `char`, and it could break on an implementation with signed `char`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, I forgot about the ambiguity of `char` when I wrote my earlier comment. So `signed char` would presumably work, just like using `int`.

Comment: Whether a given construct is elegant or idiomatic is a matter of opinion and perhaps context. There are several safe constructs. This one has a certain charm: `i=10; while(i-->0) {...}`.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion, everyone! I guess I missed the point of the "array subscript has type 'char'" warning. I thought it was to warn you of the possibility of array index going negative but apparently it's due to char's ambiguity. And, yes, using signed char doesn't generate warnings. @EricPostpischil, i != -1 feels too hacky :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop in your code indeed does not work as the test `i >= 0` is always true.  Compiling with extra warnings will spot this problem.

To avoid this problem, `i` should be initialized to `10`, the test should be `i > 0` and `i` should be decremented at the start of each iteration instead of after it:

```
    for (unsigned i = 10; i > 0;) {
        i--;
        printf("a[%d]: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
```

Combining the test and the decrement produces the classic down loop that works for both signed and unsigned index types:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[10] = { 0 };

    for (unsigned i = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a); i-- > 0;) {
        printf("a[%u]: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The test `i-- > 0` is only false for `i == 0`, but `i` is decremented as a side effect, so the first iteration uses the value `9` inside the loop body, the second uses `8`... and the last uses `0`, the value of `i` after the last decrement. The next next will evaluate to false and leave `i` with the value `UINT_MAX`.

Another advantage of this technique is `i` is initialized to the number of elements, `10`, which is also the number of iterations, not `9` as in the question code.

---

<sup>Note also that `i-- > 0` can be written `i --> 0` as explained in [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c-c). While `i-- > 0` is idiomatic in C, `i --> 0` is not.  Whether one is more elegant than the other is a matter of opinion</sup>

Answer (score 2):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

As for the loop then 1) do not use magic numbers like 9 and 2) in general use indices of type `size_t` and at last 3) declare variables in minimum scope where they are used..

Also objects of an unsigned integer type can not have negative values. For example if you will write

```
unsigned int i = -1;
```

then the variable `i` will have a very big positive value.

Try for example this code snippet

```
unsigned int i = -1;
printf( "i = %u\n", i );
```

And even the type `char` can behave as type `unsigned char` depending on compiler options.

So when the variable `i` having an unsigned integer type and value 0 is decremented it gets a big positive value. As a result there can be access outside the array or you can have an infinite loop.

Here is your updated program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    char a[N] = {0};

    for ( size_t i = N; i-- > 0; ) 
    {
        printf( "a[%zu]: %c\n", i, a[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The loop can be written also like

```
for ( size_t i = N; i > 0; i-- ) 
{
    printf( "a[%zu]: %c\n", i - 1, a[i -1] );
}
```

Comment: There's lots of good recommendations in this answer, but when you actually got to answering the specific problem you didn't explain the solution at all.

Comment: @Barmar May I ignore your comment?:)

Comment: Re “For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like”: No, that is not what the C standard says. Besides the `(void)` and `(int argc, char *argv[])` and implementation-defined manner, it allows “or equivalent”, and `int main()` in a definition is equivalent, as calling a function defined with `int main()` using a call without arguments, `main()`, is defined to work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil From the C23 Standard "5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
1 The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype
for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
int main(void) { /* ... */ }" Implementation defined declaration is not a standard declaration.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As for "equivalent" then "Thus, int can be replaced by a typedef name defined as int, or the type of argv can be written as char ** argv, and so
on".

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: C23 is not the C standard. Maybe someday it will be.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: note that `(void)` as a parameter list in function definitions is finally becoming equivalent to `()` in the upcoming C23 version of the C Standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It makes clear this paragraph because early somebody thinks as you.

Comment: @chqrlie It is not for main.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Re “It is not for main”: C 2023 draft N3096 does not treat `main` differently in this regard, and it shows at least eleven examples of defining `main` as `int main()`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: it is not explicit in **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup** but I am betting one dollar that `int main()` is meant to be equivalent to `int main(void)`.and indeed there are 2 (non normative) examples with this syntax.

Comment: @chqrlie I am sorry. I have no dollars. I am unemployed.:)

Comment: @chqrlie In my opinion there are two important points in the Standard. The first one is "The implementation declares no prototype for this function. ". And the second one is that "shall be" is shall be.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I guess I should try and file a defect report.  I will ask Jens Gustedt about this.

Comment: @chqrlie It is a good idea. Do not forget to send the answer to me.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I first asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77519368/are-int-main-and-int-mainvoid-equivalent-prototypes-in-c23

Comment: "according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like" omits the 3 _or_ in C123dr 5.1.2.2.1 1 given a false impression that there is only 1 way.

Answer (score -1):

Well, that's correct.  What you have written

```
    unsigned int i;
    char a[10] = {0};

    for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("a[%d]: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
```

of course, if `i` is `unsigned`, then the predicate `i >= 0` is **ALWAYS true**, so you will run on trouble (not by the overflow, but because you use `i` to access the `a` array.

Had you written (as `unsigned` numbers over/underflow in a predictable and precise manner)

```
    for (i = 9; i <= 9; i--) {
        printf("a[%d]: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
```